Windows ssh/git - Host key verification failed unless user is logged in
We have a scheduled job that calls an Ansible playbook targeting a Windows host. This playbook calls a Powershell script that performs a git clone of one of our Bitbucket repositories via ssh.
This works smoothly most of the time; however, the git clone action fails with the Host key verification failed error unless there is a user logged in as our service account (the account Ansible runs as).
I'm knowledgeable about what Host key verification failed usually refers to (remote key is not in the known_hosts file). I've made various unsuccessful attempts to fix this, including:

Setting the global git option -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new and even -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no

Adding a step to our script that removes and re-adds any Bitbucket keys present in the known_hosts file. I confirmed this did in fact swap the key in known_hosts


ssh-keygen -R <bitbucket host>
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new <bitbucket host>

Neither of these fixed the behavior; the job still succeeded if a user was logged into our service account, and failed if no users were connected.
For reference, the exact error is:
Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. 


Please show us your playbook (only relevant part). Increase ssh verbosity (debugging output) and show us the log. Currently there is not enough information to guess what is going on other than that: without a logged-in user the service account's home page is not available; not mounted may be.

I've heard of this happening when the user's home directory on the target host isn't accessible when they're not logged in. The home directory might be encrypted or not mounted.
